# Are the real polynomials a complete metrizable topological vector space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Recently, the following question came to me: Is there a complete metric on the space of real polynomials (equivalentely on the space of finite real sequences) so that addition and scalar multiplication are continuous? I would like to consider $\mathbb{R}[X]$ as a vector space over the real numbers equipped with their Euclidean topology.

Unfortunately, the topology cannot be induced by a norm. If this would be the case, then we would have came along a countably infinite-dimensional Banachspace, of which there are none. To avoid confusion, please note that I try to talk about the Hamel dimension, where each element can be represented as finite linear combination of a basis.

The discrete topology does not work either, because the scalar multiplication fails to be continuous, unless we consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology.

It is most certainly already well-known whether there is a metric as I wish for, but unfortunately I did not came across the right result. Could anyone give a hint?

Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: This is a very nice space provided one puts on it the topology which fits it best. It is the locally convex topology defined by the set of all seminorms on this vector space. This is also the finest locally convex topology. With this topology the space is complete but not metrizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, essentially for the same reasons applying to the normed space case.

If such a metric exists, then $\mathbb R[X]$ becomes a topological vector space.  Then, for every $n$,
$$
  P_n := \{f\in \mathbb R[X] : \text{degree}(f) \leq n\}
  $$
is a finite dimensional subspace, hence closed by Corollary 3.1.6 in [this link](http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/%7Einfusino/Lect8.pdf).  Since $\mathbb R[X]$ is supposed to be complete, it is Baire and hence the fact that
$$
  \mathbb R[X] = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} P_n
  $$
implies that some $P_n$ must have a nonempty interior. So some ball
$$
  B(x_0,r)\subseteq P_n.
  $$
Given any $y\in \mathbb R[X]$, and using that scalar multiplication is continuous, there is some $\varepsilon >0$, such that
$$
x_0+\varepsilon y\in B(x_0,r)\subseteq P_n,
$$ from which it follows that $y\in P_n$, proving that $\mathbb R[X]=P_n$, a contradiction.